# Can't disable IIS

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7.5

I cannot disable IIS.  I've tried uninstalling everything I can think of realted to it including MS Web Deploy, Web Matrix Platform, IIS express (am I missing anything?).

I tried disabling the related services, and I even tried net stop was /y at the command prompt.

All I get when I try localhost is HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

Even redirecting localhost to a different IP in my HOSTS file doesn't do anything, which used to work fine before I made the ill-fated decision to play around with Microsoft Web Matrix and IIS.

It seems to have hijacked my computer pretty good, and I've tried every thing I can think of to get it removed.  Any help?

Comment: did you look at what services are running on the machine? use netstat to see process is bound to port 80? IIS is generally disabled via the "turn windows features on or off", it is not "uninstalled".

Comment: net stat just says TCP 0.0.0.0:80 state listening.  I already  disabled it via turn windows features on and off to no effect.

Comment: I mean it's bad enough that I'll put a bounty up when it's eligible.  I've tried everything I can think of.

Comment: the PID is system btw